# Azure Automation of VM in Virtual Network?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-automation

Using `Azure Automation`, how do you connect to an `Azure Virtual Machine` on an `Azure Virtual Network`? I know how to create a VPN connection using PowerShell on a regular Windows PC, but Azure Automation does not appear to support running arbitrary processes. It's going to be difficult to automate stuff with pure PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Automation sandboxes cannot be directly connected to VPNs. There are other methods though. Please see http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/18/azure-automation-run-tasks-on-azure-virtual-machines-without-opening-ports/ and http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/04/managing-on-premises-systems-with-azure-automation/ for more details.